# Windows 7 and xampp - unable to write files using codeigniter

Tags: windows-7, php, file-permissions, xampp

I am on Windows 7 using XAMPP and am trying to write file to the default install location of `C:\xampp\htdocs` using a PHP script but I am getting write failures. I can write to my own user area. How can I allow PHP to write to `C:\xampp\htdocs`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account the security Windows 7 has in place.
Make sure that the user which apache is running with has permissions to access and write to that location.

or you could try pointing the htdocs folder to another location such as your own home folder.